# Javascript errors in simple javascript code

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have pretty simple JS

```
function () {          //**Expected identifier** over first bracket
    window.Root = {
        Models : {},
        Views : {},
        Comments : {}

    }
}
.call(this) //**Syntax error** over dot
```

But getting an errors

function **(**) - Expected identifier

**.** call(this) - Syntax error

Could some one explain why that errors talking place and how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten the parentheses:

```
(function () {
    window.Root = {
        Models: {},
        Views: {},
        Comments: {}
    }
}).call(this);
```

Because expressions cannot start with `function` or `{`, it is treated as a declaration and therefore fails. Function declarations must have an identifier, and since `.call` is completely separate from the function declaration, it is therefore a syntax error (as `.call(this)` in itself is not a valid statement).

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the paranthesis in your function.

```
(function () {          //**Expected identifier** over first bracket
window.Root = {
    Models : {},
    Views : {},
    Comments : {}

}
});
.call(this) //**Syntax error** over dot
```

Comment: Don't need the semi-colon if you're chaining the `call` method